# Почему не работает миграция БД? Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, миграция

Ранее в БД добавлялась таблица `authorization`, миграция была выполнена успешно.

Сейчас необходимо добавить в БД новую таблицу `changes`.

Скрипт миграции

```
"""added changes table

Revision ID: 9d03bec28e83
Revises: fb23259287eb
Create Date: 2020-02-13 15:07:03.684000

"""
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '9d03bec28e83'
down_revision = 'fb23259287eb'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        'changes',
        sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
        sa.Column('date', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('username', sa.String(50), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('signal', sa.String(), nullable=False),
        sa.Column('value', sa.String(), nullable=False)
    )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('changes')
```

При выполнении команды `python runner.py db upgrade` вылетает исключение

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table authorization already exists
```

Ругается на то, что таблица `authorization` уже существует.

Нашел информацию, что необходимо установить в конфиг параметр `include_schemas=True`. Но это ничего не меняет.

env.py

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
logger = logging.getLogger('alembic.env')

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
from flask import current_app
config.set_main_option(
    'sqlalchemy.url', current_app.config.get(
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI').replace('%', '%%'))
target_metadata = current_app.extensions['migrate'].db.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url, target_metadata=target_metadata, literal_binds=True
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    # this callback is used to prevent an auto-migration from being generated
    # when there are no changes to the schema
    # reference: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html
    def process_revision_directives(context, revision, directives):
        if getattr(config.cmd_opts, 'autogenerate', False):
            script = directives[0]
            if script.upgrade_ops.is_empty():
                directives[:] = []
                logger.info('No changes in schema detected.')

    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            include_schemas=True,
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

В чем может быть проблема?

- Python 2.7 x32
- SQLite3
- Flask 1.1.1
- Flask-Migrate 2.5.2
- Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.1
- SQLAlchemy 1.3.13
- alembic 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

При создании и/или удалении таблиц можно указать ключевое слово `checkfirst=True` которое добавить в SQL скрипт проверки "IF NOT EXISTS or IF EXISTS CLAUSE".

```py
t = Table('authorization', metadata,
  Column('col1', String(50), primary_key=True),
  Column('col2', String(100)),
)

t.create(checkfirst=True)
```